# String in Java : charAt Function use

Tags: java, string

Reversing a string can be done by concatenating the Original String through a reverse loop  (from str.length-1->0)

but why is this not Working Correctly :
by adding the character by character from last positon to the 0th position:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<originalStr.length())
{
    strRev.charAt(i)=originalStr.charAt(str.length()-1-i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You cannot edit a String in java, a String is unmodifable

Comment: You should look into the StringBuilder class if you want to edit a string: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html. It has a `setCharAt` method, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Strings are immutable in Java. You cannot edit them.

If you want to reverse a String for training purpose, you can create a `char[]`, manipulate it then instantiate a `String` from the `char[]`.

If you want to reverse a String for professional purpose, you can do it like this :

```
String reverse = new StringBuilder(originalStr).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strRev.charAt(i) // use to Retrieve what value at Index. Not to Set the Character to the Index.
```

All we know that `String` is a `immutable` class in Java. Each time if you try to modify any `String` Object it will Create a new one.

```
eg :- String abc = "Vikrant"; //Create a String Object with "Vikrant"
      
      abc += "Kashyap";    //Create again a new String Object with "VikrantKashyap" 
                          // and refer to abc again to the new Object.
      //"Vikrant" Will Removed by gc after executing  this statement.
```

Better to Use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to perform reverse Operation. The only Difference between these two class is

> A) **StringBuffer** is a Thread Safe (Synchronized). A little slow because each time need to check Thread Lock.
>
> B) **StringBuider** is not Thread Safe. So, It gives you much faster Result Because it is Not `Synchronized`.

There are Several Third Party Jars which provides you a Features like `Reverse` and Many more String base Manipulation `Methods`

```
 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils; //Import Statement

 String reversed = StringUtils.reverse(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test method, best practice is to use triple A pattern:
Arrange all necessary preconditions and inputs.
Act on the object or method under test.
Assert that the expected results have occurred.

```
@Test
 public void test() {
    String input = "abc";

    String result = Util.reverse(input);

    assertEquals("cba", result);
 }
```